# Making sure a checkbox stays checked when a text input is not empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to keep a checkbox checked whenever a given text input is not empty.
At the moment, the text input box isn't responding to the event I added to it through jquery, and I'm wondering if there's something off in my code. (still quite new to jquery)

Here is my text input and checkbox:

```
<input type="text" id="textInput"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" checked="checked" />
```

And here is my jquery code:

```
$('#textInput').on('click', function(){
    //if text input is not empty 
    if($('#textInput').val() !== ''){
        //if checkbox not checked, check it
        if($('checkBox').checked !== 'checked'){
            $('checkBox').checked = 'checked';
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: hey. man! you should pay attention to selectors and learn how to debug you code. I'll provide possible solution below

Answer (score 1):

You can affect the checkbox `checked` state via `.prop()` - and in this case we can just set it to the truthy `$('#textInput').val() !== ''`.

```js
$('#textInput').on('blur', function() {
  $('#checkBox').prop('checked', $('#textInput').val().trim() !== '');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textInput" />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call function to check on page load(ready), and every text field change. I didn't test my solution, but it should be fine

```
const textInput = $('#textInput');
const checkbox = $('#checkBox');

function setCheckboxState() {
  const text = textInput.val();
  if (text) {
    checkbox.prop('checked', true);
  }
}

setCheckboxState();
textInput.on('focus change keyup', setCheckboxState);
```